# Arithmetic Progression Sum of Sequence

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

The sum of the first 19 terms of an arithmetic progression is equal to twice of the value of 10th term. The value of 10th term will be?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: let $d$ be the step size for the arithmetic sequence, then the answer is $(\frac{1}{16}+9)d$.

Comment: @user42493:  But is $d$ given?  And does the sequence start at $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
For an arithmetic sequence, we have $$u_1+\dots+u_{19}=19\,\dfrac{u_1+u_{19}}2=19\,u_{10}.$$
What can you conclude from the hypothesis?